# VBscript for finding a string and replacing it with line break

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word

I need a script for finding `"`, `:` and `;` in a given paragraph and convert them into line breaks.

Example:

```
what ; when " you : like
```

should be converted into

```
what
when
you
like
```

Comment: Are you looking for VBScript (runs outside Excel) or VBA (runs inside Excel)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String
    s1 = Chr(34)
    s2 = ":"
    s3 = ";"
    s4 = Chr(10)
    Cells.Replace s1, s4
    Cells.Replace s2, s4
    Cells.Replace s3, s4
End Sub
```

Comment: which language? VB script ? chr(10) refers what? I need a line break between the words..

Comment: Within **EXCEL** it would be VBA rather than VBScript......CHR(10) returns an ASCII 10

Comment: its not working.. can u assist with me step by step.. many thanks in advance.. I will give u d sample data..

Comment: "a: b
""c: d; e;
cc: f"
"re: to
to:a; J; An;
DL"
this s the sample data.. not from the same cell. 10 cells having similar data.. and all the names should come one by one.. I mean in different cells.. kindly assist..